# How to run PHP code when pressing input button?

Tags: php, html, forms, button, call

So I have 2 different pages, 1 with a HTML Form and 1 with PHP code.
So when I press the button on page 1 where my form is, how do i make sure this code runs;

```
<?php 

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "soup") or die("Geen connectie gemaakt: ".mysqli_connect_error());
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
  if (isset($_POST["Cluster_Name"]) && isset($_POST["Cluster_FQDN"]) && 
  isset($_POST["DBS"]) && isset($_POST["Local_AE"]) && 
  isset($_POST["AE_Title"]) && isset($_POST["Modality_Type"])) {
    $Cluster_Name = $_POST["Cluster_Name"];
    $Cluster_FQDN = $_POST["Cluster_FQDN"];
    $DBS = $_POST["DBS"];
    $Local_AE = $_POST["Local_AE"];
    $AE_Title = $_POST["AE_Title"];
    $Modality_Type = $_POST["Modality_Type"];

    $qryUpdate = "UPDATE tblcluster SET Cluster_Name = '$Cluster_Name', 
    Cluster_FQDN = '$Cluster_FQDN', DBS = '$DBS', Local_AE = '$Local_AE', 
    AE_Title = '$AE_Title', Modality_Type = '$Modality_Type' WHERE 
    Cluster_FQDN = '$Cluster_FQDN'";

    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $qryUpdate)) {
      echo "Gegevens zijn niet geupdated";
    } 
    else {
      echo "Gegevens zijn geupdate.";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Your code is not executed? Do you get any error?

Comment: No erros, my code just doesnt get executed

Comment: @yasuolenmq: How have you confirmed that this code is even being invoked?  How are you invoking it?  What are the exact steps and output?  Have you turned on error reporting?  Checked your PHP logs for errors?  What debugging have you done to narrow down the problem?  Be aware also that your code is wide open to SQL injection, which is both a security hole and a very common source of bugs.

Comment: You could add an else to your second condition. This would cover the case where code is not executed because not all fields are set.

Comment: Try a var_dump($_POST) and check if all your conditions are satisfied

Comment: Posting your form code could have been useful. 
Your code is also subject to [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Either you add your html form code here
or make sure that the submit button in your form has a name attribute and form tag should have action and method attributes
like this:

```
<form action="your-php-filename.php" method="post">
<!-- OTHER FIELDS -->
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i pressed the button i just get an empty page

Comment: Like when i press the button, it just opens it but doesnt RUN it

Comment: @yasuolenmq: *"i just get an empty page"* - (1) That's often a sign of a PHP error, check the error logs.  Although, looking at your code... (2) There are multiple code paths in your PHP code which *produce no output*.  So an "empty page" is a correct response for those scenarios.  For example, if `isset($_POST["submit"])` is `false` then your code will, as instructed, produce no output.  Immediately following that condition is another, longer condition which also is explicitly designed to produce no output if `false`.  So an empty page is not necessarily a sign of a problem here.